# Textarea Character Count Including Pre Populated Text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal that on launching contains a textarea, within that text area content is dynamically added depending on the link that launches the Modal.

(Think twitter - replying to a tweet auto populates the @ of the user...)

I currently am using the following to count my characters;

```
$('#post_reply').keyup(function () {
var max = 140;
var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len > max) {
        var ch = len - max;
            $('.characterLeft').text('Characters Remaining: - ' + ch );
            $('#reply-characters').attr('class', 'exceeded');
            $('.post-reply').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Disable submit button as over char limit
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
            $('.characterLeft').text('Characters Remaining: ' + ch );
            $('#reply-characters').removeAttr('class');
            $('.post-reply').removeAttr('disabled'); // Enable submit button as char count below MAX
    }
});
```

Which is working fine, I plan to refine it as I'm sure it could be written better - however - at present it does not amend the character count until I begin typing.

As such it shows 140 characters left, when in fact it is 140 minus the length of the dynamically loaded text now within the box.

Is it possible to have the modal load and already count the existing characters?

I have been the .keyup line as I hoped I could amend this to trigger the function, however as jQuery n00b I'd really appreciate some pointers / guidance?

Here is my modal;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="replyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="replyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="replyModalLabel">New message</h4>
            </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="post_reply"></textarea>
                <div id="reply-characters"><span class="characterLeft"></span></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary post-reply">Post Tweep</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and also the link that is launching it;

```
<a href="#" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#replyModal" data-whatever="@userName" title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
```

The below populates my Modal with the data from the above href..

```
$('#replyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-title').text('Reply to ' + recipient)
      modal.find('.modal-body textarea').val(recipient + ' ')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply trigger `keyup` event after you load the textarea which will run the code inside your handler

```
$('#replyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-title').text('Reply to ' + recipient)
      modal.find('.modal-body textarea').val(recipient + ' ');
      /* now trigger keyup */
      $('#post_reply').keyup();
});
```

I'm a bit confused about the selector mismatch and why you use `modal.find()` for the textarea and not just use the ID. I assume they are the same.

Could likely simplify to

```
$('#post_reply').val(recipient + ' ').keyup();
```

Comment: don't you like it when solutions are a lot simpler than what you might have anticipated!

Comment: haha I do indeed, sometimes I need to remind myself it isn't always something super complicated and a little touch here and there can really have a big impact! Thanks again for the help.